# I am using jQuery Mobile with a number of other JS Frameworks, notably Bootstrap.js and DHTMLX.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, hyperlink, dhtmlx

My problem is that jQuery Mobile inserts into my  and the other frameworks link tags   a class="ui-link" which then renders the  links inoperable. As soon as I turn off jQuery Nobile all the class="ui-link" insertions disappear and the program behaves properly except for lack of jQuery Mobile features.

The environment is XAMPP local server on Windows 8.1 using all 5 major browsers.

My question is twofold. First, have others run into this problem? Second, is there a simple work around [besides switching to jQuery-UI]?

Thanks

Comment: For elements that you want jQuery Mobile to ignore, add the attribute data-role="none".

Comment: Do you want to handle _deep linking_ yourself without the help of JQM?

Comment: Sometimes the order you have Js files may help. sometimes